# how to check check box and getting whether checkbox is checked in javascript selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, checkbox

how to check check box and getting whether checkbox is  checked in javascript selenium and node.
I tried using .click on the element also tried using native javascript code to do that.but nothing worked for me.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('//*    
[@id="myTable"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input')).
then(function(element){
   element.click().then(function(){//body goes here

};
```

I have edited the code in SO itself so there might be braces problem.in actual code its not the braces problem.

any solutions to do so?

Comment: Please share code with question which you have tried.

Comment: @HelpingHands..i have put the code snippets

Comment: @HelpingHands.. i have already developed other testcases in javascript itself

Comment: @HelpingHands..I think u didnt post it  yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change webdriver.By.id to webdriver.By.xpath as you are using xpath here